# ethers web3provider can't connect to metamask the second time

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask, ethers.js, web3-providers

I am developing a React NFT marketplace on Polygon where a user can create, buy and relist an NFT. The issue is I am unable to connect to Metamask/web3provider for the second time after successfully executing first time buy. Error on console is

> -32603: Error: Transaction reverted: function call failed to execute"

The snapshot of the error is attached below.

[image]

My preliminary understanding is that the problem is arising from "buyNft" function that gets triggered after clicking "buy" button.

```
async function buyNft(nft) {
// console.log("I was able to hit buyNFT")
const web3Modal = new Web3Modal()
const connection = await web3Modal.connect()
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection)
// console.log("web3 provider", provider) // There is no change in this output in both successful and failed buy transaction.

const signer = provider.getSigner()
const contract = new ethers.Contract(nftmarketaddress, Market.abi, signer)

const price = ethers.utils.parseUnits(nft.price.toString(), 'ether')
const transaction = await contract.createMarketSale(nftaddress, nft.tokenId, {
  value: price
})

await transaction.wait()
loadNFTs()
history.push('/myassets')
}
```

The nft I am passing as argument to buyNft() function is an object and it looks like this

```
{
description: "Using Dev 1 Account"
image: "https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/QmUksTHetYR6if3yeTx6ckLoqDCgnFdjwVNHGiiideMw7X"
name: "Demo 1"
owner: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
price: "100.0"
seller: "0x8626f6940E2eb28930eFb4CeF49B2d1F2C9C1199"
sold: true
tokenId: 1
}
```

I am supposing that this error pertains to web3modal and not including the code for loadNfts() function, createMarketSale smartcontract and Market.abi. Please let me know if I you need them.

Another interesting thing to note is that, if I navigate to create page and create a new NFT, buyNft function works fine and opens metamask. But after the first time, it is again throwing the same "-32603-Internal JSON RPC error" for subsequent clicks.

I tried other variations of web3modal such as passing window.ethereum into Web3Provider, not passing connection into web3provider and using JsonRpcProvider. But any of them didn't work.

This seemed like a garbage collection issue at first so I added useEffect to cleanup. Not sure if it solved anything other than memory leaks and issue still remains.

Please let me know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone stumbles upon this question, it is working fine now. I deleted the cache and artifacts folder, restarted the hardhat node and redeployed the contracts again along with resetting the accounts on metamask.